# How do I show $(a, b)$ is incomplete?

Tags: real-analysis

If I take the sequence $\{a + 1/n\}$, then it's Cauchy and the limit as $n$ goes to infinity is $a$, which completes the proof. Is this correct?

Edit: I doubt this is the right approach because the sequence we're choosing isn't guaranteed to be inside the interval. Is there a fix to this issue, or (why?) is this not an issue at all?

Comment: What you really need to show is that the sequence does not converge to any point in $(a,b)$. That it converges to a point outside the interval is none of your business :)

Comment: A metric space (like an open interval) is incomplete iff there is at least one Cauchy sequence that does not converge (to anything inside that space). Remember, if your space is the interval $(a, b)$, then the point $a$ _does not exist_.

Comment: Your sequence is good, to avoid any trouble just let $n$ be larger than the integral part of $1/(b-a)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the sequence you suggested if we 'fix' the first few points by multiplying the $1/n$ part with a constant $c$, which guarantees that $a + c/n \in (a,b)$. For example, you could use $c =(b-a)/2$, although any $c \in (0, b-a)$ would do the trick. So for the sake of simplicity lets use $c = (b-a)/2$.

We then have $a_n := a + \frac{b-a}{2n} \in (a,b)$. You can verify that this indeed is a Cauchy sequence. Now, we need to show that this sequence does not converge to any point $x \in (a,b)$. To do this, we can actually use (in this special case) that $a_n \to a$.

Let $x \in (a,b)$ be any point. Then $(x-a)/2 > 0$ and we know that $1/n \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$. Hence, there exists some $N >0$ such that 
$$\frac{1}{n} < \frac{x-a}{b-a}$$
for all $n \geq N$. It follows that 
$$\frac{b-a}{2n} < \frac{x-a}{2}$$
and
$$a_n = a + \frac{b-a}{2n} < a + \frac{x-a}{2} = x - \frac{x-a}{2}$$

Thus,
$$|x-a_n| > \frac{x-a}{2} > 0$$
for all $n > N$. Hence, $a_n$ can not converge to $x$.